# tkinter grid positioning of frames

Tags: tkinter

I think I need reevaluate the personal perception of my own intelligence as I just cannot grasp how to use tkinters **grid** control in the context of what I want to do. The multiple references I've looked up are quite case specific and for highly variable contexts and are sometimes beyond me; I can't adapt them successfully. Here's an image of what I want to achieve (which I guess could be a quite useful setup for others).

Obviously I have two rows, row0 contains two columns, with one frame in each column (pink frame1,  and green frame2 respectively). I will want have frame1 being a static width that can be hardcoded. While row1 at the bottom is a frame to act as statusbar as well as holding widgets).

I want to be able to hide frame1 on row0 via a radio/toggle button on the status bar or menu, hence resize frame2 to span the entire x-axis, and of course, revert back to default layout (frame1 & frame2 in row0 and width frame2 spanning the entire x-axis minus width of frame1) after another toggle.

Lastly how to apply 'grid' to frame3 to accommodate multiple labels and widgets so that they don't overlap and shuffle along should, say, one labels text length goes from 5oC to 32.5oC

My skeleton erroneous code for the frame positioning currently ended up like this:

```
# pink frame1
frame1=tk.Frame(root, bg='pink')
# Need: col height = window height - statusbar height)
frame1.grid(row=0)

# green frame2
frame2=tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
# Need: col height = window height - statusbar height)
frame2.grid(row=0)

# statusbar
frame3=tk.Frame(root, bg='white', height=50)
frame3.grid(row=1)
```

I've tried sticky, expand=True, rowspan etc., in various ways - other than in the correct way of course!

[image]

I'm fine now with making menu(bars), frames, canvases, Comboboxes labels and other widgets. I had been using the **place** method/property to set out objects, but It seemed place had no 'span' feature for when users will change the main window size, hence had to turn to 'grid'.

Could someone please give clear guidance as how to achieve the desired positioning? Thank you so much in advance for any help offered.

---

Based on what Brian said in his early comments, I got this to work....

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()

root.geometry("700x500") # x,y # how to use variables instead of a weird string???
root_x=700
root_y=500

status_bar_height = 25
frame1_width = 200

# frame1 (pink) to display data etc
frame1=tk.Frame(root, bg='pink')
frame1.place(width = frame1_width, relheight = ( (root_y - status_bar_height) / root_y) )

#frame2 (green)
frame2=tk.Frame(root, bg='lightgreen')
frame2.place(x=frame1_width, relheight = ((root_y - status_bar_height) / root_y), relwidth=1)

# frame3 (white statusbar)
frame3=tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
frame3.place(height=25, rely=.95, relwidth=1)
```

Tq Bryan and for later code you posted after your initial hint.

Comment: note: you can use `place` and still have the widgets grow and shrink when the window is resized. Even so, `place` is almost always the wrong tool for the job. `pack` and `grid` make it much easier to create responsive, maintainable layouts.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that, but how to do it? I couldn't find a way to do on the spot resizing in tandem with main window resizing using 'place', that I felt forced to use 'grid'.
`frame3.place(x=20, y=100, #??? = syntax for span function - either here in at the frame3 object creation stage)`

Comment: `place` has the ability to relative positioning (`relx`, `rely`) and size (`relwidth`, `relheight`).

Comment: OK. Thanks very much for the tip Bryan. I'll investigate that. If I get it working I'll add the working code the original post in case it proves useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes being made in your code:

- you don't give two of the frames a size, so they will default to one pixel each
- you don't tell grid to allocate extra space to any of the rows and columns, so by default they will be as small as possible to fit the widgets in their requested size
- you don't use the `sticky` attribute to force the frames to fill the space allocated to them
- you don't specify any columns, causing frames 1 and 2 to overlap
- you don't have the bottom frame span all of the columns

### Explanation:

By default `grid` only uses as much space is necessary to render the widgets at the requested size. In your case, for two of the frames the requested size isn't set so the frames are just one pixel each.

The solution is to add weights to your rows and columns, which tells `grid` how to allocate all of the extra space. The default weight of 0 specifies that the row or column is not given any extra space. Positive integers define how much of the space is allocated relative to other rows and columns.

So, you should give a non-zero weight for any row or column that you want to be able to grow or shrink to accommodate its children. In your case you want the first row to grow or shrink, but the second row should not. You also want both columns to grow or shrink, though it's not clear if you want them to grow/shrink at the same rate or if you want most or all extra space to be given to the frame on the right.

A good rule of thumb is that you should always give at least one row and at least one column a weight whenever you use `grid` to layout widgets in a parent.

Once you've done that, you need to use the `sticky` attribute to make sure the frames fill the space that has been allocated.

Finally, as another rule of thumb, you should always specify both the row and column for each widget rather than accepting the default value of zero.

### Solution

**Note:** I've found that layout problems are much easier to solve when you group all layout code together for each group of widgets. I will use that technique in the following code.

You said you want the left frame to have a static width, so we'll give it a hard-coded width, and give the second column a weight so it gets all of the extra space.

I'm also going to give the root window an explicit size so that it's easier to visualize. Once you put other widgets inside the frame this step won't be necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

frame1=tk.Frame(root, bg='pink', width=100)
frame2=tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
frame3=tk.Frame(root, bg='white', height=50)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
frame3.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan. My "v.2 code" still was erroneous but your beautiful and efficient code is the best help in getting me over this hurdle. I really appreciate the explanation also - it has helped a lot.